# How to access session variable in SSRS 2005 reports

Tags: reporting-services

I want to access the session variables in SSRS 2005 reports just like we access in c#.

session["username"]

I want to access like this in SSRS report.

I want to print the login name of the user who logged into the application. But I dont to pass it as parameter to report. In the application, I am storing the login user name in session variable and using it in several places. Is there any way to use it in SSRS report in the same way.

Is there any way to achieve this??
Can we access it in custom code in SSRS?

Answer (score 0):

Try using User!UserID (either by typing it in, or selecting it from the Globals list in the Edit Expression dialog).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a hidden parameter and pass your session variable in. The parameter would not be visibile to the end user.